# Trying to make a fixed menu with a background

Tags: html, css, menu, header, fixed

Hey there I wanted to create a white background for my menu on the right and title on left just like on this website http://weblendit.co.uk/, that also stays at the top when you scroll down (doesn't necessarily have to change its size like this one)

My header also consists of a big picture after the nav and h1, when I set a background color it will only be behind the text, but I want it to be fullsize.

I also tried setting a width and height for **.fixed** but then the nav floats to the left and the h1 disappears?

```css
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

h1{
    padding: 1% 0 0 4%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
}

nav{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 12%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    width: auto;
    right: 0;
}

#menu ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu li{ 
   margin: 0 5%;
   float: left;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <h1 class="fixed">My page</h1>
    <nav class="fixed" id="menu">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="travel/index.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
  ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to fix the container surrounding the `header` elements, rather that every element in it. Then you don't need the `fixed` class anymore.

```
<header class="header">
    <h1>My page</h1>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="work/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="travel/index.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```